# Equality of inner and outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

I have the following elementary Lebesgue measure theory question:

Let $E\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with $|E|_e$ finite. Then $E$ is measurable if and only if $|E|_i = |E|_e.$

I wrote the following proof:

Let $\epsilon >0$. A set $E$ is measurable if and only if there exist an open set $G\supset E$ and a closed set $F\subset E$ such that
$$
|G\setminus E|_e <\frac{\epsilon}{2}
$$
and
$$
|E\setminus F|_e <\frac{\epsilon}{2}
$$
Now since $G\setminus F = (G\setminus E) \cup (E \setminus F)$, we have
$$
|G\setminus F|_e \leq |G\setminus E|_e + |E\setminus F|_e< \epsilon
$$
by the above inequalities. Thus, $E$ is measurable if and only if $|E|_i = |E|_e$.

What's wrong with this proof? I never use the fact that $|E|_e$ is finite.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument proves that if $E$ is measurable then $|E|_i=|E|_e$. It does *not* prove the converse statement that if $|E|_i=|E|_e$ then $E$ is measurable.